# AAB on Internal Testing in Google Play not "available to testers within minutes" or even days

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I deployed an app in Google Play to Internal Testing, but I still see an older version of the app (from 10/13) when click on the link to download/install. I get the link from the Testers tab of Internal Testing:
[image]

I have released 3 more times but the older version (release 22, 10/13) is still the only one which can be downloaded.

In Google Play it says release 28 (the latest release, increment it by 2), is "Available to internal testers", but when I click on the testers tab and "Copy link" and send to testers, they pull up release 22. I see the old release notes and release date.

[This Play Console Help link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en&visit_id=637701220704305107-3209920676&rd=1#zippy=%2Cwhy-should-i-run-an-internal-test) says that "When you publish a new Android App Bundle to the internal test track, it will be available to testers within minutes." and I am using an AAB.

I would think that if the release showed that it was available to internal testers:

[image]

Is anybody else having this issue? I just can't move forward if I cannot deploy to internal testers.

Comment: Some of the more obvious things to check would be: 1) the users that are trying to install the test version have been added as testers in the Google Play Developer Console. 2) the new versions of the app is compatible with the testers' devices.

Comment: To add to #1 from Michael, make sure the testers are signed into the Play Store on that device with an email listed in the testers group, and that they have uninstalled any versions of the app previously installed for any other account on the device

Comment: They can download the app, just not the latest version. They have been added. They can get to the older version so I think that confirms: they are a tester and are logged in. The link is the same link for all versions and takes me to a screen that asks to uninstall if the app is installed. It has been uninstalled at this point.

Comment: @Michael, are you saying if the version of the app is not compatible with the version of the device, the older version would show? I did not think that was they way it worked

Comment: I have the same problem.
Testers can download the app from internal testing but not the latest build, even thought  in console says " Available to internal tester".

Comment: @lcj Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Zima, no. I still deploy and sometimes it is available in ten minutes or so, but most of the time it might take a few days. I really wish there was some rhyme or reason to it so I could provide guidance to test users. Also I've tried to use In-App Updates to control things, but I don't believe this is applicable to Internal Testing.